# Angular: Reuse *ngFor elements in another div

Tags: angular

I work on an application that needs to display different stacked images according to a well defined order.

1 -> image

2 -> grid

3 -> image

4 -> grid

Where the numbers represent the z-index of the elements, which are on the same level.
One performance improvement that I want to make is to reuse the *ngFor from the 2nd grid in the 4th one, since the grids need the same data, and to not loop through it twice.

```
<div class="parent>
  <div class="first-pic"></div>

  <div class="first-grid">
    <div *ngFor="let element of arrayData"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="second-pic"></div>

  <div class="second-grid">
    <div *ngFor="let element of arrayData"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is how my structure currently looks, where the parent elements (the ones with classes, have z-index set, and the grid ones use the "grid-template-rows" and "grid-template-columns" for showing rows and columns).

Is there anyway to somehow not iterate twice through the same array?

Answer (score 2):

how about this approach?

```
<ng-template #content>
 <div>{{whatever}}</div>
</ng-template>


<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-container>
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the ts page:
Add method :

```
extractArray(){
    let extractedData:string = "";
    for(let i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    extractedData +='<div>'+value of 
    the extracted array
    data[i]+'</div>';
    }
    return extractedData;
}
```

And in the :

```
ionViewWillEnter {
    let divData:string = 
    extractArray();
    let div1 =document .getElementbyId('first-div');
    let div2= document.getElementbyId('second-div');
    div1.innerHtml = divData;
    div2.innerHtml = divData;
}
```

And in your html :

```
<div class="parent> 
<div class="first-pic"></div>
 <div class="first-grid"> </div> 
<div class="second-pic"></div>
 <div class="second-grid"> </div> 
</div>
```